# How do I get the timezone using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timezone, moment-timezone

How do I get the timezone using javascript? instead of America/New_York I want "Eastern Time - US/Canada 5:13pm" with the timestamp and country.

How can I get that using React/Javascript? just like Calendly has it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date.toLocaleTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)